# Different type of Node created

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

On geeks for geeks I saw a different way to create the Node for linked list.

```
struct Node{
   int data;
   Node* next;
   Node(int x){
      data = x;
      next = NULL;
   }
}
```

Can someone please explain me how that node is defined.

Comment: That looks like a standard linked list to me. Can you explain what confuses you?

Comment: @Pubby What does this mean:        Node(int x){
      data = x;
      next = NULL;
   }

Comment: That's the constructor.

Comment: It looks like you could use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Check this reference  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 struct Node {
     int data;
     Node *next;
     Node(int x) : data(x), next(NULL) {}
 };
```

This is just a way to define structure with constructor in C++

You can use them simply like this

```
Node *node = new Node(4);
```